# Delete Postman Cookies

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-native-app, postman-mocks

Is there any way to expire authtoken in postman saved after login call?
I have tried to code get response object

```
{
tests["Login successfull"] = responseCode.code === 200;
var token = postman.getResponseCookie("authtoken");
console.log(token)
}

this is  object am getting 
{
name: "authtoken"
expires: null
maxAge: 0
domain: "cdn.contentstack.io"
path: "/"
secure: true
httpOnly: true
hostOnly: true
value: "rxE1TWD13Ji1dRCQK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Postman collection can automatically detect an expired access_token value and request a new one by using the refresh_token. By default this feature is enabled *but it can be turned off by setting the **enable_auto_refresh_access_token** Postman environment variable to false*

Reference [LINK](https://developer.box.com/guides/tooling/postman/refresh/)